# How can I search in my computer for some txt files inside GUI?

Tags: matlab, file-io, matlab-guide

I am using the Matlab Guide function in order to build an inteface with the user. Nevertheless, I need to read some arrays that are in 5 different txt files. I would like to run my guide application, and using any command, start to search my computer and load these .txt files into my program. How could I easily do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you want to load these text files by default when starting the GUI, you could do it in `GUI_OpeningFcn(...)`. Text files can be parsed using the Matlab function `dlmread(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is a built-in function that will do that for you, so either you have to loop through some `dir` commands yourself or grab a file from MATLAB Central / File Exchange: e.g. [DIRR](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8682-dirr-find-files-recursively-filtering-name-date-or-bytes) or [subdir](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15859-subdir-a-recursive-file-search).